# Fail to get the Spark job log when running Spark on Yarn with Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I have a Hadoop HDFS and Yarn cluster where I run Spark jobs, and by default, I did not enable the "yarn-log-aggregation".

Then, after enabled Kerberos, I configure the HDFS & Yarn to run with Linux account "app01" and with the kerberos principle&keytab with the same name "app01", and generated some user specific principles and keytabs, taking the end user "user01" as example (there is no such Linux account).

Then, when I run "kinit" to authenticated as "user01", and submit a job, I cannot view its job log from Yarn web GUI (the "logs"):
I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3A9J.png)
Then when I click into any of them, I got the exception:

```
Exception reading log file. Application submitted by 'user01' doesn't own requested log file : stderr
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7TxL.png)

When I checked from Linux, I can see that in the working node, the Linux log files were created with Linux "app01" account, but looks the Yarn is expecting log files to be owned by "user01", which is impossible.

---

Then from here, I try with the second solution: enabling the "yarn-log-aggregation".
I added the below configuration into yarn-site.xml, and restarted HDFS & Yarn.

```
 <property>
     <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
     <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
     <value>86400</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec</name>
     <value>600</value>
 </property>
```

When things up, I kinit to become "user01", and submit another spark job. After job done, I tried to view log from yarn GUI's "Logs" link, and then got this exception:

```
Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.
```

Then I tried to check the log from Spark UI, when drilling from "stdout" or "stderr" links in Spark UI, I reached the same place with same exception as above.

Then, I gave another try, to use "yarn logs -applicationId xxxx" to get the job log, and then got the exception:

```
Can not find any log file matching the pattern: [ALL] for the application: application_1588684192939_0001
Can not find the logs for the application: application_1588684192939_0001 with the appOwner: user01
```

Then I checked the yarn's log from the worker node, and can see several exceptions, repeated of the below one:

```
2020-05-05 14:10:31,450 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat: Error aggregating log file. Log file : /opt/disk1/data/yarn/userlogs/application_1588684192939_0001/
container_e57_1588684192939_0001_01_000001/stdout. Owner 'app01' for path /opt/disk1/data/yarn/userlogs/application_1588684192939_0001/container_e57_1588684192939_0001_01_000001/stdout did not match expected owner 'user01'
java.io.IOException: Owner 'app01' for path /opt/disk1/data/yarn/userlogs/application_1588684192939_0001/container_e57_1588684192939_0001_01_000001/stdout did not match expected owner 'user01'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.checkStat(SecureIOUtils.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.forceSecureOpenForRead(SecureIOUtils.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openForRead(SecureIOUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat$LogValue.secureOpenFile(AggregatedLogFormat.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat$LogValue.write(AggregatedLogFormat.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat$LogWriter.append(AggregatedLogFormat.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.filecontroller.tfile.LogAggregationTFileController.write(LogAggregationTFileController.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl$ContainerLogAggregator.doContainerLogAggregation(AppLogAggregatorImpl.java:581)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl.uploadLogsForContainers(AppLogAggregatorImpl.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl.doAppLogAggregation(AppLogAggregatorImpl.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl.run(AppLogAggregatorImpl.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService$1.run(LogAggregationService.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So for now, **the problem is, after enabling Kerberos, the end user no longer able to view the Spark job log**, no matter yarn GUI, Spark UI, or yarn command line. What I can only get is checking the logs from Linux file system or from HDFS log aggregation folder (which is not allowed to be accessed by end user).

Can anyone show me any idea please?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Smells like an issue in the filesystem privileges -- e.g. a missing "sticky bit", or existing dirs for existing users that have not been reset when Kerberos was set up. Could you install a Hadoop sandbox, with Kerberos and log aggregation pre-enabled, and check what privs are set on Linux (for YARN logs of running containers) and  HDFS (for collected logs of finished jobs)?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for the reply. When i submit a job with "app01", the Linux log permission is 640 owned by app01 (the real Linux user), and the log aggregated in HDFS are also 640 and owned by app01.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.

```
Exception reading log file. Application submitted by 'user01' doesn't own requested log file : stderr
```

And then, I check the stdeer in the nodemanager. I found out that every file's owner is yarn.

```
[root@hostname container_e32_1657581531728_0024_01_000002]# ll
total 2964
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn        yarn   28088 Aug 12 20:52 directory.info
-rw-r----- 1 yarn        yarn    6527 Aug 12 20:52 launch_container.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn        yarn       0 Aug 12 20:52 prelaunch.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn        yarn     100 Aug 12 20:52 prelaunch.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn        yarn 2991908 Aug 14 19:29 stderr
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn        yarn       0 Aug 12 20:52 stdout
```

Meanwhile, every container's owner in nodemanager is yarn as well.

Then I noticed that the reason may be linux executor.
In conf yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class is as DefaultContainerExecutor, in which case, every container will run using yarn user.

LinuxContainerExecutor could run every container as the user who submitted the application.

Help this can help you.